# How do I attach the token, realmID, and secret when batching with the quickbooks-ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, quickbooks

```
gem 'strong_parameters', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'quickbooks-ruby'
gem 'quickbooks-ruby-base'
gem 'oauth-plugin'
```

Rails 3.1.3 - ruby 1.9.3p194

I can successfully make a single call to the API by doing:

```
base = Quickbooks::Base.new(current_user, :invoice)
```

Where current_user holds: qb_token, qb_secret, and qb_company_id.

However when I create the object:

```
  batch_req = Quickbooks::Model::BatchRequest.new
```

I am not sure how to pass in current_user.

I have also tried using:

```
 access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(@user.qb_company_id, @user.qb_token, @user.qb_secret)
```

But again, I am not sure how to pass the access_token with the batch command.

Comment: in `OAuth::AccessToken.new(@user.qb_company_id, @user.qb_token, @user.qb_secret)` first argument is $qb_oauth_consumer which you created in your initializers file along with your QB_KEY and QB_SECRET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`access_token`,`access_secret`,`realm_id` are always send using `Quickbooks::Service` not `Quickbooks::Model`. So create `batch_service` and attach access_token and realm_id with it. Here is a sample code to create batch_service

```
access_token               = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, @user.qb_token, @user.qb_secret)
batch_service              = Quickbooks::Service::Batch.new
batch_service.access_token = access_token
batch_service.company_id   = @user.realm_id
```

and now send your `batch_req` using this service

```
batch_response = batch_service.make_request(batch_req)
```